# Javascript question--what is "window"?

Tags: javascript, android, window

```
<html>
    <script language="javascript">
        /* This function is invoked by the activity */
        function wave() {
            alert("1");
            document.getElementById("droid").src="android_waving.png";
            alert("2");
        }
    </script>
    <body>
        <!-- Calls into the javascript interface for the activity -->
        <a onClick="window.demo.clickOnAndroid()"><div style="width:80px;
            margin:0px auto;
            padding:10px;
            text-align:center;
            border:2px solid #202020;" >
                <img id="droid" src="android_normal.png"/><br>
                Click me!
        </div></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

My question is: What is "window.demo.clickOnAndroid()"?

**I know that clickOnAndroid is a method in my Android application. But what is window and demo? My file is called demo.html. Is that it?**

Comment: "My file is called demo.html. Is that it?" No. It's a method, called "clickOnAndroid" on the "demo" variable. But I don't know what it is specificly, so I'm not posting this as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`window` is the [javascript window object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp):

> The window object represents an open
>   window in a browser.

`window.demo` means that a `demo` object has been assigned as a property (or instance variable) of `window`, so `window.demo.clickOnAndroid()` means that you are invoking `clickOnAndroid()` on the `window`'s `demo`. Therefore `demo` is the name of the instance of your Android application, your real application would be up to you to name, so your invocation would probably look like `window.serious.clickOnAndroid()`.

Answer (score 0):

[Window](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp) is one of the top level DOM objects[(1)](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/default.asp)[(2)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model).  Demo is a non standard property implemented by Android.